# difference between bfs for sssp and dijkstra

Tags: python-3.x, dijkstra

my bfs code is this:

```
def bfs(graph, source, distance: dict):
    queue = [source]
    visited = [source]
    distance[source] = 0
    while queue:
        deVertex = queue.pop(0)
        for neighbour in graph[deVertex]:
            if neighbour not in visited:
                queue.append(neighbour)
                visited.append(neighbour)
                distance[neighbour] = distance[deVertex] + 1
```

Here, the `visited` part comes immediately after we add the vertex to the queue

my dijkstra code is this:

```
def dijkstra(source):
    heap = []
    heappush(heap, [0, source])
    distance[source] = 0
    while heap:
        dist, node = heappop(heap)
        visited.add(node)
        for child_dist, child_node in graph[node]:
            if child_node not in visited and distance[child_node] > distance[node] + child_dist:
                distance[child_node] = distance[node] + child_dist
                heappush(heap, [distance[child_node], child_node])
```

Here, `visited` comes after we `pop` the vertex from the heap

I don't understand why answers are wrong in either of them when we change the `visited` position
i.e.
when putting `visited` after `pop` in bfs OR when putting `visited` after appending to the heap in dijkstra